# How to find total resistance of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, ohms-law

[image]

I have a terrible prof who didn't teach anything about this. I understand how to find parallel and series resistances, but am thrown off by the 4 Ω resistor in the middle.

Comment: total resistance between which two points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to use the [delta-wye transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) on either the upper or the lower three resistors. This will reduce the network to a series and parallel combination of resistors which you should be able to solve easily.

The other way is to apply [Kirchhoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), which will give you a system of linear equations to solve. You can solve any resistor network with this method so it will probably more useful to you in the long run. The common way to systematically apply Kirchoff's laws is [nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis). [Mesh analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis) is another option, although you would end up with one more more equation than with nodal analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another idea to find the equivalent resistance using Thevenin's theorem.

### OP's circuit...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPktDq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### ... presented as two coupled voltage dividers...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f43hfH.png)</sup>

### ... and two coupled real voltage sources

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKmioV.png)</sup>

Comment: Hmm… now I see that this was actually Andy's idea…

Answer (score 3):

> *am thrown off by the 4 Ω resistor in the middle*

The important 4 Ω resistor is the one that I've designated \$R2\$ below. I've simulated your circuit so you can see what you will eventually derive for the node voltages: -

[image]

OK, my simulator has already solved this and labelled the voltages and currents so, immediately you can see that the current taken from the 80 volt source is 9 amps and, this means the load resistance on the 80 volt source has to be 8.8888 Ω. This of course is the answer you are looking to derive.

However, because you don't want to use a simulator, the important thing to try and find are the voltages shown as 28 volts and 40 volts either side of \$R2\$ above (and \$R7\$ below).

I have redrawn the original diagram using a source transformation: -

[image]

Basically I've duplicated the 80 volt battery and hopefully the circuit looks a bit easier to solve using more source transformations. Nothing has changed in the node voltages and currents i.e. they are identical to the original circuit simulated.

Finally, there are two more source transformations and these are shown in the picture below: -

[image]

The source transformation on the left combines \$R6\$ and \$R9\$ in the 2nd picture into \$R11\$ immediately above. Basically they are paralleled. To complete the source transformation, the 80 volts has to be reduced by the resistive divider ratio of \$R6\$ and \$R9\$.

The source transformation on the right follows the same rules.

The important thing to note is the the voltages either side \$R13\$ remain exactly the same as in the previous pictures. Same story for the current flowing (3 amps) in \$R13\$.

So, you manipulate your original circuit into the bottom circuit and you have some fairly simple number crunching to find the 40 volts and the 28 volts.

Once you have those node voltages you can go back to your original circuit and solve for all the other currents.